# Execute sql dump file

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to create the table and add all the records present in the .sql dump file..

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysqldump -u root -p org < database_name.sql
Enter password: ****
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.15, for Win64 (x86_64)
-- Host: localhost    Database: org
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.7.15-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS,  FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE,SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'*/;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2016-12-24 23:38:01
```

after completing the above command..i am not seeing any table in my database.

```
[no tables in the database][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OhTU.png

thanks

Comment: to use database type **use database_name**

Comment: so instead of "connect database" , i can use like "use database_name " ?/ is it

Comment: your question related to mysql server then why are you tagg **sql-server**? remove this

Comment: after import dump .sql file you can use database  by this mysql command **use database_name**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `mysqldump` use `mysql` instead.

```
mysql -u root -p org < database_name.sql
```